# In jupyter notebook what should I do about frozen modules warning?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to merge 2 data frames when I got this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKDOi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEKVu.png)

I'm stuck on why this is happening. does anyone have an answer to this problem?

I tried restarting and searching for a way to add Xfrozen_modules=off to my configuration but without success.

Comment: Please include your code and the text of the error message in your question. It makes it much easier for people to see your code and not have to click on untrustworthy links.

Comment: That part about frozen modules is just a warning. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/debugger-warning-it-seems-that-frozen-modules-are-being-used-python-3-11-0/16544/9?u=fomightez). You'll see `python -Xfrozen_modules=off -m jupyterlab_server` listed there and you'll want to use something like that. Or set the setting `PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1` like also mentioned there.